# How to find out information about an EC2 instance from AMI id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

This gives me information about all the snapshots I have:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots
```

From this, I can extract AMI id and find out more about the ami using:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids "ami-xxxxxxxx"
```

My question is, can we relate the ami id and instance that are using that ami id and find more information about it?

Comment: The AMI does not point to Instances. Rather, Instances use AMIs can you can discover which instances are using the AMIs.

Answer (score 4):

Run `describe-instances` with the `image-id`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=image-id,Values=ami-xxxxxxx"
```

For text output:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=image-id,Values=ami-xxxxxxx" --output text
```

Comment: It gives me the following output:

{
    "Reservations": []
}


Any idea why?

Comment: If the result is empty, then there is no instance that was launched with that AMI